# Calculating the power of the four different normality tests and which test is the most powerful?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

To compute the power of a normality test I should generate the data using a non-normal distribution, correct? So does anyone know which code to use for a t-distribution with degrees of freedom n = 30, 15, 8, 4 and sample sizes T=10,30,50,100,500.

**It is useful to conduct the analysis to see which test is the most powerful, but how?**

The four tests I'm doing are the following (here only for T=10):

```
sw10 <- shapiro.test(rnorm(10))
jb10_1 <- JarqueBeraTest(rnorm(10), robust = FALSE)
jb10_2 <- JarqueBeraTest(rnorm(10), robust = FALSE, method ="mc", N = 1000)
Lf10 <- LillieTest(rnorm(10))
```

My coding is different every time, I am trying to improve it every day, the method I found to work as well was the following:

## Normality tests

## Sequence to follow for each sample size to find columns

```
remove(reject1, reject2, reject3, reject4)
reject1 <- FALSE
reject2 <- FALSE
reject3 <- FALSE
reject4 <- FALSE
sample.size <- 500 #here I change the sample sizes resp. 10,30,50,100,500
x <- 0.01 #here I change the significance level resp. 10%, 5%, 1% 
for (i in 1:1000)
{
  simulation <- rnorm(sample.size)
  sw <- shapiro.test(simulation)
  jb1 <- JarqueBeraTest(simulation, robust=FALSE)
  jb2 <- JarqueBeraTest(simulation, robust=FALSE, method = "mc", N = 1000)
  Lf <- LillieTest(simulation)
  reject1 <- cbind(reject1, sw["p.value"]<x)
  reject2 <- cbind(reject2, jb1["p.value"]<x)
  reject3 <- cbind(reject3,jb2["p.value"]<x)
  reject4 <- cbind(reject4, Lf["p.value"]<x)
}
```

Comment: The function `rt` will give you random samples from a students t.

Comment: The “power” of a test is the probability of rejection of the null under a specific alternative. There typically is no “most powerful” test. Furthermore the use of a random vector from the t-distribution will not be a particularly interesting challenge against which to judge a suite of candidates.

Comment: @DWin So I can conclude there is no most powerful test & it is not necessary to test this by using some sort of code in R?

Comment: Clue? You want a clue? The "most powerful test" will be one which _always_ rejects the Null. I thought I gave you a clue. Think about the Alternative. The challenge is to achieve some sort of balance between the competing objectives of rejecting the Null when the Alternative is true and accepting the Null when it is not. You have not correctly stated your question to include a proper consideration of how the Alternative hypothesis is formulated. Further clue: Normality is not normal.